# MySQL merge tables with different structure

Tags: php, mysql, merge, merging-data

I have two databases with different structure.

Table 1:

```
ch_code    ch_def    ch_weight
```

Table 2:

```
address    ch_code
```

I need to merge this two tables, so the structure would look like:

```
ch_code    ch_def    ch_weight    address
```

The number or rows in two tables are different (table 1 has more data).

Should I use `merge`, `union`.. something else?

Thank you!

Comment: Well, it depends on what do you want on the resulting table...
It will probably help if you add some sample data.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean you have 2 tables within the same database and are looking for a query that will result in the columns you have indicated?

Comment: Are there columns which relate the tables?  For example, a person_id which represents the same row in both tables.

Comment: Yep, 2 tables within the same database and ch_code is the same for table 1 and table 2.

Comment: Define "merge".  Do you mean create a brand new, permanent table.  Or simply retrieve the merged data into an application for temporary use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution which should handle the three possible cases:

1. There's a ch_code value in t1 that's not in t2
2. There's a ch_code value in t2 that's not in t1
3. There's a ch_code value in both t1 and t2

`SELECT t1.ch_code, t1.ch_def, t1.ch_weight, '' as address from t1 where not exists (select * from t2 where t2.ch_code = t1.ch_code)`

`UNION`

`SELECT t2.ch_code, '' as ch_def, '' as ch_weight, t2.address from t2 where not exists (select * from t1 where t1.ch_code = t2.ch_code)`

`UNION`

`SELECT t1.ch_code, t1.ch_def, t1.ch_weight, t2.ch.address from t1 left join t2 on t1.ch_code = t2.ch_code`

Once you've obtained that resultset then you may do your INSERT INTO if you have a new table for housing the merged data.

Comment: PS - Anybody know the secret to get a multiline code block that contains underscores to look right?  I had to settle for backticks on each line.

Answer (score 1):

If Table2 only has data that's included in Table1 (i.e. there's nothing in Table2 that's not in Table1), you should be able to do something like (assuming Table3 has been setup already):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE3 (ch_code, ch_def, ch_weight, address)
SELECT Table1.ch_code, Table1.ch_def, Table1.ch_weight, Table2.address
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 on Table1.ch_code = Table2.ch_code
```

(I don't have a MySQL install handy, so your specific syntax my vary.)

If you have data in Table2 that doesn't match data in Table1 (and you want to keep that data), you'll need a FULL JOIN (if MySQL doesn't support that, UNION a LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN).